# HTML - Is it possible to container Views?

Tags: jquery, html

So, i am pretty new to static HTML programming as I only used Angular for nearly a year as a frontend 
framework.

### What I want:

- I want to have a static homepage without using a huge framework or a NodeJS-server in the background.
- The Homepage should have more than one page (obviously)
- I also want to avoid duplicated code

### My Idea:

From programming in Java I know the concept of inheritance (and also composition...) and thus I thought it could be nifty to have one Start-Page which includes the subpages as containers.
It could also be compared with using Latex-Documents: build one Main-File with the settings and make the chapters contain only the text.

### My Approach:

As a starting point I have got an index.html-File.
In this file is the -Element defined (which uses the jquery `$().load("url")`-feature to include the header from an outsourced file)
I have also a menu-bar on the left side with one `<ul>`-list and many `<li>`-elements.
Those li-Elements reference to possible sub-pages by adding their prefix to the current url as parameters, e.g.:

`https://<my-homepage>.com/index.html?my-subpage`

On any redirect there will be an jquery-script triggered, which tries to load the subpages into the div-container 
When the parameter does not fit to a present subpage, a default page will be loaded.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="./resources/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/logo.ico">
    <script src="resources/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:hidden">

<header id="header" class="header">
    <script>
        $("header").load("./header/header.html");
    </script>
</header>
<hr>
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="?subpage">Subpage</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="?subpage2">Subpage Two</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="container" class="main">
        <script>
        var param = window.location.search.substr(1);
        var url = './' + param + '/' + param + '.html';

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        if(http.status==200){
            $("#container").load(url);
        }else{
            $("#container").load("./default/default.html");
        }

        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### My Question (in detail):

First of all I want to gather experience on this subject:

- Is this a good approach or are there better alternatives?
- Is it even possible with static HTML and some JavaScript to load a dynamic site like this?

Comment: If you want to create static HTML, why don't you create static HTML? Instead `https://<my-homepage>.com/index.html?my-subpage`, why not `https://<my-homepage>.com/my-subpage.html`, without the need for any dodgy client-side jQuery page loading *at all*? There are numerous "static page" CMS available.

Comment: This site has a comprehensive list: https://www.staticgen.com/

Comment: thank you for this site - didnt know there were something like this and i will definetly have a look at this!
The main reason for the jquery-loading is the concentration of configuration in ONE file and not to retype the configuration in every .html file again... but this seems let me use my framework (angular, vue whatever) and build a static website, am i right?

Comment: Technically that would be possible, not sure if there is a framework that does it, but it's worth checking out. On the other hand seems like overkill to me write a full Angular application only to have it rendered in static HTML at the end.

Comment: There are many dedicated HTML templating languages, things like Markdown or Handlebars, and with the proper build tool you can keep all your content in plain text files. HTML is created automatically as as part of the build step - which is exactly what many of those CMS tools do. Seems like a better fit for a static page to me.